# Cannot query correct record use rowkey in hbase

Tags: hbase, cloudera

I have a Hbase table, containing about 80,000,000 records. The rowkey format is `customerno_yyyyMM` or `customerno_yyyy`, like for example `b2d545316e39414da42961d414d6b5fe_201901` and `b2d545316e39414da42961d414d6b5fe_201910`, the length of customerno is 32.

Now I meet a problem : when I use rowkey `b2d545316e39414da42961d414d6b5fe_201910` to query data, I get a record for which rowkey is `b2d545316e39414da42961d414d6b5fe_201901`.

By the way, the rowkey `b2d545316e39414da42961d414d6b5fe_201910` and `b2d545316e39414da42961d414d6b5fe_201901` both exist in the table.

Comment: can you please format this elaboration

Comment: @DulajKulathunga what's your mean

Comment: Could you please format this Because  of  Not clear , when someone see your question

Comment: @DulajKulathunga sorry,it's my first time commit a problem in stackoverflow

Comment: Now it is okay ,clearly we can see question

Comment: Can you show the actual scan that you run please?